# AWS - "AccessDeniedException" calling lambda function from Amazon connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud

I am new with the aws api and system in general and im currently working with three parts of aws;

Connect
Lambda
Lex

I am trying to get connect to call a lambda function with a simple parameter, but i am getting this error in cloudwatch;
[cloudwatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM2J3.png)

I tried a google search but it seems that everyone thinks it is IAM related, even though i have a role with the right permissions;

[lambda role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0YtD.png)

and detailed;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwCIS.png)

it looks like the trigger is already there [image: connect permission]

Does anyone know why i can't get to invoke my lambda function? Permissions should be fine, i think...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a "Trigger Policy" which allows AWS Connect to invoke your AWS Lambda.

You can configure it through the AWS CLI:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name function:my-lambda-function --statement-id 1 \
--principal connect.amazonaws.com  --action lambda:InvokeFunction --source-account 123456789012 \
--source-arn arn:aws:connect:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/def1a4fc-ac9d-11e6-b582-06a0be38cccf \
```

> This command uses the following input:
>
> - The name of the Lambda function (for example, my-lambda-function)
> - The ARN of a Amazon Connect instance (for example,
>     arn:aws:connect:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/def1a4fc-ac9d-11e6-b582-example) - To find the ARN for your instance, open the Amazon Connect console,
>     and then choose the Instance Alias to open the Overview page.
> - The AWS account ID for the Lambda function (for example, 123456789012)

For more details please check the Documentation: [Using AWS Lambda Functions with Amazon Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html)

Comment: it looks like the policy is already there. please take a look at the picture :-)

Comment: Nope. This policy allows only "Lex" to call you Lambda but you need to allow "Connect" to invoke your Lambda as well.

Comment: my bad - connect is also there i just screenshotted the wrong thing. its updated

Comment: I was using the wrong ARN - problem is solved, thanks